# C# decode, edit and encode frames in an AVI file

Tags: c#, image, avi

I am developing a C# App to edit my AVI file. I want to decode, modify and encode it.
This is the process I would like:

1. load each frame from my AVI file into a temporary bitmap in memory.
2. modify the bitmap. (This is not a simple edit).
3. write the bitmap into the same file or another file.
4. destroy the bitmap.
5. repeat for all frames
   Is there a nice and simple way to do this?

I have tried "A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library" but could not get it to compile.

And: kaitai'w work but I think it is old and cannot parse new AVI files.

My favorite would be AForgeNet but I have tried various things with no luck.
This is my very simple code:

```
using AForge.Video.VFW;

namespace Aforge1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnTest1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AVIReader reader = new AVIReader();
            reader.Open("C:\\CSharp\\testBasics\\test2.avi");   //error occurs here
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Previously it threw this error on the reader.Open() command:

> AForge.Video.VideoException:'Failed initializing decompressor.'

But I think I've broken something else and now I get this error:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

I know my AVI file exists. I have added all references to the AForge DLLs.
Please help me use AForgeNet (or something better).

Comment: What codec was used for this file?  The AVI file format hasn't changed in nearly 30 years, so the term "new AVI file" isn't really meaningful.

Comment: You might also look at OpenCV.  https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp

Comment: Thanks. OpenCV looks really good. I got the C# files.
But I try to run the Video Writing sample and it seems to be working but then fails with this error:

[ERROR:0@4.515] global cap.cpp:656 cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised unknown C++ exception!
Converting each movie frames...
621 / 621
[ERROR:0@11.031] global cap.cpp:185 cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised unknown C++ exception!

Comment: Were there 621 frames in this file?  Perhaps you should show the OpenCV code you tried, maybe in a new question.

Comment: After further investigation AForgeNet and OpenCV do not support writing audio to AVI. This is unfortunate because I need that functionality. But, I have found SharpAvi which does what I need - but when I try to run the solution I get this error:

A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly. In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project.

I have tried everything that makes sense regarding that error with no luck. Sorry about my formatting.

Comment: That's a completely separate question.  You created your C# project to create a library, when you actually wanted to create an executable (I assume).  You may need to create a new project and copy the files over.